# speeding up udf on large data in R/sparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, udf

I use spark 2.1.0 running locally on a single 16-core node with ample of memory.  I loop over ~50 files of 250M lines each.  In the UDF stage I have a  SparkDataFrame of two strings.  I apply an UDF which is just a table lookup, replacing one column (cell) to the corresponding "division" (integer):

```
cellToDivision <- function(df) {
  ## convert dataframe with cell to the one based on division
  division <- distCell[as.character(df$cell)]
  data.frame(unname(df$msisdn),
             unname(division),
                       # remove names -> otherwise data.frame tries to
                       # use NA for rowname for missings and fails
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
             check.rows=FALSE)
```

}

`distCell` is a named vector of integers of length ~10000.

My problem is that the code that applies the UDF:

```
dapply(df, cellToDivision,
    structType(structField("msisdn", "string"),
               structField("division", "integer"))
    )
```

is terribly slow taking about 2h to run for each dataset.  In case of 250 partitions the code just hangs there, 5000 partitions will run on 4h, 50k partitions in 2h; 500k partitions seems to give me 6h per file.

250M rows by 2 columns should be well within the capabilities of this node.  Do I do something wrong?  Are UDF-s in R always that slow on real-sized datasets?

Comment: I know I can replace the table lookup by a corresponding merge.  However, previously I have had the impression that (in pyspark) broadcasting the table and doing the dictionary lookup as a UDF is the preferred way.

Comment: Using UDFs is not a preferred and R UDFs are incredibly slow (serde overhead) for now. If lookup is small enough it should be autobroadcasted when joined (It doesn't look like Spark R has `broadcast` bindings right now).

Comment: Thanks, so you essentially say that what I see is what one expects in R?  I guess this is because of the current inefficient serializer?

Comment: I am not sure about expected by definitely it is a consistent behavior. R -> JVM transfer has been reduced significantly in 1.5 or 1.6 but for more consistent behavior we'll have to for Arrow I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record--this particular task was easily solved by replacing table lookup in udf by a merge:

```
cdrDist <- cdr %>%
     merge(cellDistrict, by="cell", all.x=TRUE)
```

where `cellDistrict` is a SparkDataFrame containing columns `cell` and `division`.  Now it takes <10min to run a dataset.